# Почему не могу инициализировать slick при удалении из контроллера

Tags: angularjs, slick.js

Использую слайдер [slick-angular](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick). Вот его разметка:

```
<slick dots=true slides-to-show="10" slides-to-scroll="10" arrows="false" ng-if="Products.length" init-onload=true data="Products.length"> 
            <div ng-repeat="item in Products">
                <img height="80" width="105" src="https://www.supercars.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2003_Lexus_IS430Concept3.jpg" />
                <small>{{item.Name}}</small>
            </div>
        </slick>
```

Имеется кнопка по нажатию на которую удаляется элемент в коллекции `slick`. Есть функция которая находится во вьюшке и отлично работает:

```
var Upp = function (id) {
    $('.slicker').slick('unslick');
    var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById('root')).scope();

    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.Products.splice(5, 100);
    });
    $('.slicker').slick();
}
```

Однако мне нужно чтобы вызывалась функция которая в отдельном файле, в контроллере. Выглядит она примерно так:

```
app.UpdateDetails = function (item) {

        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Products.length; i++){
            if ($scope.Products[i].Id == item) {          
                $('.slicker').slick('unslick'); // тут уже не работает
                $scope.currentProduct = $scope.Products[i];
                $scope.Products.splice(i, 1);
                $('.slicker').slick(); // тут уже не работает
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
```

И в данной функции unslick и slick вроде как работают (но это не точно), слайдер дергается как-будто произошло удаление, а потом все элементы остаются прежними. Хотя длина коллекции становится на один элемент меньше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение на англоязычном *stackoverflow*.

1. Добавляем `ng-if="dataLoaded" init-onload="false" data="dataLoaded"` к нашему слайдеру.

   ```
    <slick dots=true slides-to-show="10" slides-to-scroll="10" arrows="false" ng-if="dataLoaded" init-onload="false" data="dataLoaded">
                   <div ng-repeat="item in Products">
                       <img height="80" width="105" src="https://www.supercars.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/2003_Lexus_IS430Concept3.jpg" />
                       <small>{{item.Name}}</small>
                   </div>
               </slick>
   ```
2. Добавляем в начало нашей функции `$scope.dataLoaded = false;` контроллера и по завершению изменяем на `true`

   ```
       app.UpdateDetails = function (item) {for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Products.length; i++){
           if ($scope.Products[i].ExtId == item) { 
               $scope.dataLoaded = false;
               $scope.currentProduct = $scope.Products[i];
               $scope.Products.splice(i, 1);
               $timeout(function () {
                   $scope.dataLoaded = true;
               });
               break;
           }
       }       
   }
   ```